# python filter doesn't work

Tags: python, lambda, filter

I have an algorithm that can generate a prime list as a generator:

```
def _odd_iter():
    n=3
    while True:
        yield n
        n=n+2

def _not_divisible(n):
    return lambda x: x % n > 0

def primes():
    yield 2
    L=_odd_iter()
    while True:
        n=next(L)
        yield n
        L=filter(_not_divisible(n), L)

x=1
for t in primes():
    print(t)
    x=x+1
    if x==10:
        break
```

But if I put the lambda function into the `filter` function directly, like below:

```
def primes():
    yield 2
    L=_odd_iter()
    while True:
        n=next(L)
        yield n
        L=filter(lambda x: x%n>0, L)
```

I can get only an odd list, not a prime list. It seems the `filter` function doesn't work.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried changing it to `lambda x=x: ...`?

Comment: This is seriously weird.

Comment: The first version of the algorithm does not work for me at all. The following code: `_ = primes(); print next(_); print next(_); print next(_);` prints `2`, then `3`, then hangs. What version of python are you using?

Comment: It works on python 3 but not 2.

Comment: First version works for me on Python 3.50. Is anyone getting an error in Python 2? Can't check it on my current machine.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simpler program which illustrates the same problem.

```
adders = []
for i in range(4):
    adders.append(lambda a: i + a)
print(adders[0](3))
```

While one would expect the output to be `3`, the actual output is `6`.
This is because a closure in python remembers the name and scope of a variable rather than it's value when the lambda was created. Since, `i` has been modified by the time the lambda is used, the lambda uses the latest value of `i`.

The same thing happens in your function. Whenever `n` is modified, all the lambda functions in the various filters also get modified. So, by the time the iterator reaches `9`, all the filters are filtering factors of `7`, not `5` or `3`.

Since, in your first approach you are creating a new scope with each call to `_not_divisible`, the function works as intended.

If you absolutely must use a lambda directly, you can use a second argument like this:

```
def primes():
    yield 2
    L=_odd_iter()
    while True:
        n=next(L)
        yield n
        L=filter(lambda x, n=n: x%n>0, L)
```

Answer (score 4):

The lambda that works is `lambda x, n=n: x%n != 0`. You apparently need to do this if you want `n` to be captured at the time the lambda is defined. Otherwise a lambda only looks up the variable name when it gets around to evaluating the lambda. In your case I think that meant locking onto an `n` value in a later iteration of the while loop.

Comment: What is the difference in the way closures are working in Python 2 vs Python 3?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No difference ... however this code relies on python 3 since in python 3 `filter` returns a generator rather than a computed value.

Comment: @donkopotamus OH of course! You should post that as that as the answer.

Comment: @donkopotamus Nevermind, actually, I had misread the question from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks @Trevor, your answer is also very helpful.